# Как отредактировать текстовый файл из командной строки ubuntu который находится в архиве?

Tags: ubuntu, tar

Как я могу отредактировать файл somefile в архиве по пути folder.rar/folder.jar/folder/somefile?

Comment: Распаковать. Отредактировать. Запаковать.
Но вообще идея редактировать что-то внутри архива выглядит странно.

Comment: vim поддерживает редактирование файлов внутри архива, jar и zip и tar точно откроет, а вот в rar придется поигратся

Comment: UserTest013, благодарю